# How to loop through all rows and specific columns to compute a function?

Tags: r, loops

I am not sure why I am getting the error " longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"? I have run a similar code with different dataframes and it seemed to work.

```
  feature mean sample1 sample2 sample3
1       a    3     4.0       8       7
2       b    4     3.4       3       6
3       c    5     2.0       5       7
```

Here is the code I am working with:

```
datalist6 <- matrix(nrow=length(unique(Data$feature)), ncol=length(sub), 
                    dimnames=list(unique(Data$feature), unique(sub)))

sub <- colnames(Data[, 3:46])
for (i in Data$feature) {
  for (j in sub) {
    subset <- filter(Data, feature == i & sub == j)
    func <- j/subset$mean
    datalist6[i, j] <- func
  }
}
```

This code will then throw that error. Essentially I am trying to compute coefficient of variance with mean in column subset$mean and variance of samples in columns 3:46 (sub). I am trying to run through nested for loops to determine the coefficient of variance for each row (features) for each column.

Comment: It appears you may be using `dplyr::filter`, please be explicit about non-base packages you are using. Something seems questionable: you use `length(sub)` before defining it, suggesting that the creation of `datalist6` is using a previous version of `sub`, this could easily cause problems.

Comment: `sub <- colnames(Data[,c(3:46)])`, so `sub` is a vector of column names. `for (j in sub)`, so `j` is the name of a column each iteratrion. `filter(Data, feature==i & sub==j)`. I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with `sub == j` here, but since `sub` and `j` are all about columns, they don't belong in a `filter` statement which is all about values in rows. `j/subset$mean` you can't divide a column name by a value. Maybe you want `Data[[j]] / subset$mean`?

Comment: I would strongly suggest using more descriptive variable names to make your code clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I substituted a lot of the variables. Sub represents columns 3:46 since those columns consist of variances, whereas column 2 has the mean. j in sub is there to loop through columns in sub to calculate coefficient variance (variance/mean).

Comment: I'd think `length(sub)` is fine (given that it returns the number of columns and is used to define `ncol=`), but ... still, it is used before it is defined. ***AHA***, `length(sub)` will always work since `sub` is a base R function. In this case, it may be returning 1, since similarly `length(mean)` (or length of any function) returns 1.

Comment: the datalist6 is an empty matrix, which will be filled with calculated output. I thought it was okay to put it there. It seemed to work for my previous codes (putting it before it was defined).

Comment: Adding to @GregorThomas point about more descriptive variable names: using object names the same as base R functions can cause problems. While R generally knows which one you want, this code should have failed with a more clear error. You are also using `subset` as a name, another common base R function.

Comment: Drashti, it doesn't matter that you intend it to be empty. You **think** that the first time you run this code that `length(sub)` will return the number of columns that you expect (44 given `3:46`), but the first time you run this, your empty matrix has only 1 column. The first time you try to assign to column 2 or beyond, *it will fail*. Move your `sub <- ...` assignment to *before* the `datalist6` assignment then retry your code.

Comment: Further, because you define `sub` to be `colnames(..)`, then `j` is a character, which means that `j/subset$mean` makes no sense. (And then naming that number as `func` seems ... further obfuscating.)

Comment: Since it appears you're using `dplyr`, does `summarize(Data, across(sample1:sample3, ~ . / mean))` (replacing all of your code) produce the intended output?

Comment: @r2evans I think you need a `group_by(feature)` in there, but then that's it as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's really hard to tell, tbh.

Comment: Sorry for so many mistakes in my code, I'm relatively new to R. "sub" wasn't actually used in my code (it might have been a bad choice as a substitution for this post).

Comment: @r2evans, your suggestion worked! summarize(Data, across(sample1:sample3, ~ . / mean)) I do lose my "feature" column but I can figure this out. I can't believe I overcomplicated this. I didn't use the group_by(feature), I guess I don't need it? 

Thank you, everyone!

Comment: You lost your `feature` column in your method too, I was mimicking what I thought that was doing. Instead use `summarize(Data, feature, across(sample1:sample3, ~ . / mean))` and you won't lose it. It would be helpful for you to go through tutorials on the `dplyr` package (starting with https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/ and certainly venturing out for others) to learn better how to get things you need like *this* out of `mutate` and `summarize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `for` loop required.

With the assumption that you are using `dplyr`,

```r
library(dplyr)
summarize(Data, feature, across(sample1:sample3, ~ . / mean))
#   feature  sample1  sample2  sample3
# 1       a 1.333333 2.666667 2.333333
# 2       b 0.850000 0.750000 1.500000
# 3       c 0.400000 1.000000 1.400000
```

If you instead need a base R solution,

```r
cbind(Data["feature"], subset(Data, select = sample1:sample3) / Data$mean)
#   feature  sample1  sample2  sample3
# 1       a 1.333333 2.666667 2.333333
# 2       b 0.850000 0.750000 1.500000
# 3       c 0.400000 1.000000 1.400000
```